# Create a Drag and Drop funcationality for dynamic layout with different size images for android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

Im creating an android app which has a dynamic layout for example various tables with different sizes i need to use drag and drop functionality for the tables to move around and replace.

The issue Im facing is that if i move a small size table to large size the size of the images also get large. Im receiving all the images from server and does not have any fix layout.

Im using Java for developing the android project

Comment: Are you using RecyclerView? If images are loaded inside RecyclerView items, when user reorders an item, your data set will be changed and ViewHolder will be bound to the new content (image in your case). Dimensions of ViewHolder will change based on size of the new image, unless you have set fixed dimensions for the ViewHolder. If the ViewGroup containing ImageView and ImageView itself don't have fixed size and you chose the right image scale type, there shouldn't be any problem. If you provide more information I might be able to help better.

Comment: yes we are using recyclerview and images will be of different size.

Comment: If you edit the question and add your codes and layout related to the RecyclerView and drag and drop functionality, we might be able to help you diagnose the problem.